# python 2.7 import scipy

Tags: python, scipy, cx-freeze

I create an excutable with cx_Freeze

```
    import sys
    from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
    import scipy
    import os
    base = None
    build_exe_options = {"packages": ["os","sys"], "includes":   ["pandas","sys"]}
    setup(  name = "diao",
            version = "0.1",
            description = "application!",
            executables =   [Executable("symao.py", base=base)])
```

Now i create the excutable, and run it , i have this error

```
 ImportError: Error importing scipy: you cannot import scipy while
    being in scipy source directory; please exit the scipy source
    tree first, and relaunch your python intepreter.
```

Comment: Its all in the error message. `please exit the scipy source
    tree first, and relaunch your python intepreter` Just open your interpreter elswhere

Comment: THanks @Gàbor Erdos i am not in scipy source, i am in my work repisotory